# Adding a Jitpack dependency using intellij build system

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, jitpack

Making a new Kotlin project using the IntellIJ build system (managed by the IDE). I would like to add a dependecy hosted on jitpack to my project: https://jitpack.io/#OldManAlpha/Monopoly-Deal/

There's info on the IntellIJ website on how to add a dependency here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html as well as how to add a new maven jar location: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#configure-custom-remote-repo, however after adding jitpack.io to this I'm still unable to find the monopoly library when searching.

I could switch back to gradle/maven however this seems like something that should be possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to type a full path to the artifact. For example: `com.github.OldManAlpha.Monopoly-Deal:mdclient:v0.7` under `File | Project Structure | Libraries | From Maven...`

[image]