# Adding Jitpack library to Intellij build system

Tags: intellij-idea

I converting gradle to IntelliJ build system, but most library from jitpack only and "No file were downloaded for ~~" message.

What i tried steps...

1. File -> Project Structure -> Library -> New Project Library (+ button) -> From Maven -> Add jitpack library url
2. Close IDE and delete .idea folder
3. Invalidate Caches (All check)
4. Manually add download library from jitpack (but dependency library too many, so i give up)

[Adding a Jitpack dependency using intellij build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76992084/adding-a-jitpack-dependency-using-intellij-build-system)
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uurZw.png)
I found this answer but not working.

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing the issue for more detailed error log.

Comment: @y.bedrov Here's log https://pastebin.com/U4ATVTUf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by add jitpack repository from Intellij settings.

**Settings | Build, Run, Deployment | Remote Jar Repository | Maven Jar Repository**
Click add button and add https://jitpack.io

Now, you can use jitpack repository.